# Curved box using css

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have tried to design like below image, still am not getting the result, please help me. Any help would be appreciated

[image: Desired image effect]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#rcorners1 {
    border-radius: 10px 90px 90px 10px / 8% 100% 100% 8%;
    background: #18b1a0;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="rcorners1">Rounded corners!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is some code to start with `border-radius: 10px 90px 90px 10px / 8% 100% 100% 8%;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

Comment: @Krusader Thank u, i have update with your code, But I need some dark color to left side as shown in image.

Comment: Use a `pseudo-element` for that (`:before` or `:after`) and take it from there

Comment: @GaneshPutta you can use `background-image: radial-gradient(circle at -60%, #108e80 40%, transparent 0);` or `pseudo-element`.

Comment: check this fiddle for a start - http://jsfiddle.net/nGRwt/1699/

Answer (score 2):

Using the comment by [@Krusader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8744767/krusader), you could add position: relative; to #rcorners1. Then add a pseudo element (::after) with the following CSS:

```
#rcorners1::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: -15px;
width: 30px;
height: 80%;
background-color: green;
border-radius: 100%;
}
```

So the complete CSS would look like this:

```
#rcorners1 {
position: relative;
background: #18b1a0;
padding: 20px; 
width: 200px;
height: 150px;   
border-radius: 10px 90px 90px 10px / 8% 100% 100% 8%;
overflow: hidden;
}
#rcorners1::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: -15px;
width: 30px;
height: 80%;
background-color: green;
border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Will this helps ::

```
#rcorners1 {
    border-radius: 10px ;
    background: #18b1a0;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;  
    position: relative;
}

#rcorners1:after {
  content: '';
  background: #18b1a0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 0px 36px 36px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A different solution to the pseudo-element ones would be using the [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) (as recommended by [Krusader in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785196/curved-box-using-css#comment80516938_46785196)). You could combine two different `radial-gradient` as the background-image: one for the darker shadow on the left, and another for the curve on the right border. You may need to play a little bit with the end of the transparency so it is not too sharp nor too blurry.

Something like this:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata');

.box {
  width: 190px;
  height: 109px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Inconsolata;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at -52%, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 36%,  transparent 37%), 
                    radial-gradient(circle at 29%, #18b1a0 88%, transparent 89%);
  border-radius: 6px 25px 25px 6px;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">SECRET<br/>CHAMBER</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is many kind of shapes. You can grab idea from it.
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

And i have update your code

```css
#rcorners1:after {

  bottom: 10px;
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 0;
width: 50px;
left: -35px;
background-color: #098a7c;
border-radius: 70px 100% 100% 70px;
}

#rcorners1 {
position: relative;
background: #18b1a0;
padding: 20px; 
width: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 150px;   
border-radius: 10px 130px 130px 10px / 10px 100% 100% 10px;
}
```

```html
<p id="rcorners1">Rounded corners!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 #content {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width : 400px;
    height :  200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
   }

   #rconer-big,
   #rconer-small {
    display: inline-block;
    width : 200px;
    height : 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    margin : 0;
   }

   #rconer-big {
    background-color: skyblue;
   }


   #rconer-small {
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : -190px;
   }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p id="rconer-big"></p>
  <p id="rconer-small"></p>
</div>
```